# How can I turn td content into an icon?

Tags: php, html, css, sql

By downloading data in the form of a table from the database, I plan to do visualizations. Its part is changing the icon depending on the status of one of the columns. For example, if the value of the third column is 10 we have one icon and if 30 it is another.
[table printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq7MC.png)
All elements are fetched by loop:

````
foreach ($rows[0] as $key => $row) {
  # code...

  $columns .= '<th>' . $key . '</th>';
}
// Loop for inserting values into cols by rows
foreach ($rows as $row => $col) {
  # code...


  foreach ($col as $key => $value) {
    # code...
    $rowsHTML .= '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
  }

  $rowsHTML .= '</tr>';
}```

What is the easiest way to style a suitable element?
````

Comment: Please provide some additional insight like what is your actual issue?

Comment: I looking for informations how can I style <td> elements. I want to have an icon instead of the text in that cell.

Comment: Search for "php conditional styling". Some of the results is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457663/give-style-based-on-php-condition , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344558/conditionally-format-html-table-values

Comment: Thanks for answering but it's no method that I'm seeking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you load an image where the filename is the `$value` as the src attribute?

```
foreach ($col as $key => $value) {
    # code...
    $rowsHTML .= '<td><img src="/img/directory/here/' . $value . '.png" /></td>';
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I tried Your solution and it seems it might work. At the moment I'm getting 404 because sftp can't reach .pngs